# Which layout manager should I use for this application?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I am trying to design this scholarship application, but I'm stick figuring out which layout manager to use. Till date, I've only used BorderLayout, and so I'm a bit new to the game.

Attached is the screen shot, what should my approach be? All the entries inside a JPanel of a specific layout manager?

Also, how would I have the 'scholarship name', deadline inside that green rectangle background

[image: my screen shot]

Comment: Also look at [this excellent example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/1076463) of @AndrewThompson . Nesting layouts is the way to go for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't just use *one* layout manager but instead should nest containers, each using its own layout. For instance, the JPanel held by the JTabbedPane could use BorderLayout, and in its NORTH position, hold a JPanel that uses BoxLayout. In the main BorderLayout-using JPanel's center position you could have a JScrollPane that holds a JTable that uses a custom cell renderer...

Comment: I was thinking of using a JPanel for each scholarship application, how would I use a table for it?

Comment: @afturk: You could use a JPanel held by another JPanel in a `GridLayout(0, 1)`, the holding JPanel being held by a JScrollPane. The key is to read the layout manager tutorial and to experiment.

Comment: Would you recommend doing it manually, or using the netbeans GUI editor?

Comment: I've tried reading the Layout manager tutorial, but it confuses me at times, give my exact requirements.

Comment: @afturk.khan: definitely do it manually. Consider re-reading the tutorial with an eye to using multiple nested JPanels each with its own simple layout manager.